# Facebook android sdk download error

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

HI,

I am trying to download facebook sdk for android as mentioned in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

I installed git on windows machine. Then on git bash, i executed 
git init
and then git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git

But i get an error:
Cloning into facebook-android-sdk...
fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (No such host is known. )

Any idea how to download the facebook skd? Am i missing any step?

Rgds,
Sapan

Comment: cd "the path were you want to put facebook sdk"
then just right:
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git
and then import it in eclipse it should work (it worked for me)

Answer (score 4):

You can [download](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/archives/master) complete archive with sdk.

Comment: cool...i downloaded the zip file.. to use it in my application do i need just the apk or other files also?

Comment: You may also use example of application from that archive and samples (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/) from facebook.developers site

Comment: You don't need the apk file. You should "Select File -> New -> Project (in Eclipse), choose Android Project, and then click Next.
Select "Create project from existing source".
Choose either examples/simple or examples/stream. You should see the project properties populated."                            http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile#android

Comment: If using android studio no need to download zip just add gradle dependencies:     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'